Running on docker-compose: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.12' (using password: YES)
The configuration below works just fine on my local machine:
My docker-compose.yml file:
networks:
    mynet:
        name: mynet
        driver: bridge
services:
    mydb:
        container_name: mydb
        image: mysql:8.4.2
        hostname: mydb
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: default_db
        networks:
            - mynet
        volumes:
            - ${DATA_VOLUME}:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - ${EXPOSE_PORT}:3306

    myadmin:
        container_name: myadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.2.1
        hostname: myadmin
        depends_on:
            - mydb
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mydb
            # PMA_PORT: 3306 - I tried with this parameter too
            # PMA_ARBITRARY: 1 - I tried with this parameter too
            # MYSQL_USERNAME: "root" - I tried with this parameter too
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        networks:
            - mynet
        ports:
            - ${PMA_EXPOSE_PORT}:80

And here is the .env file:
ROOT_PASSWORD=mystrongpwd
DATA_VOLUME=/path/to/my/colume
EXPOSE_PORT=3333
PMA_EXPOSE_PORT=4444

But when I'm trying to login to myadmin, I get this error:

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
'root'@'172.26.0.12' (using password: YES)

UPDATE:
So, there is a question here:Enable remote MySQL connection: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user which causes this question to get closed by the users. but that is not the answer. I found the answer and I post it below.

What is the value of your ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} value in your myadmin service? Is it just a typo or should it pint to ${ROOT_PASSWORD}?

Either your user name and/or password is incorrect, or the user does not have access to the requested resource. None of this is really a programming issue...

Hi guys. This question has some other answer. Please re-open it so I post the answer. @Shadow

Is it a programming answer or just configuring your infrastucture? If the latter, the question should not be on SO in the first place.

I changed these to things and all works fine:
# in environment section:
environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    # the rest of envs

# also I had to add this command:
command: ["mysqld", "--mysql-native-password=ON"]

I'm using mysql:8.4.2 and it seems to enabling password login with root just needs the ["mysqld", "--mysql-native-password=ON"] command.
Also, it's pretty new to me, but login from another container was not allowed unless I added the MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%' part.

Tgis is why you were wrong to discount the duplicate question as now you can access the mysql from any host. Answers to the duplicate question suggested granting access to the specific IP address only. Btw the problem was that your root@ipaddress account did not have necessary access rights. This is not a programming question.
